# Do I pay tax if I convert INR to CAD to use in Canada

Tags: taxes, india, canada-revenue-agency, cad-canadian-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

If as a Canadian resident, I hold an NRE account with an Indian bank and i transfer money earned in CAD to this account. The I earn interest in rupees and want to transfer back to CAD.
The interest is tax free in India for NRE account, but when I convert them to CAD to use in Canada, do I pay tax to CRA? Assumption is that I already paid tax on the original CAD which i transferred to india

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified version of now-deleted comment

Chris Rea points out that Canada taxes world-wide income (as does the US).
Thus, you should be reporting the interest earned each year on your annual tax return and paying taxes on that. *When* you convert these monies from INR to CAD
for the purpose of bringing them back to Canada is irrelevant as far as the
taxation of the interest is concerned, that is, you do not pay tax at the time
of conversion, you pay the tax when the *tax return for the year in which
the interest was earned* is filed. 
*If
you have not been reporting the interest earned in your NRE account
on your tax returns, I recommend filing amended returns for the years
that you missed.*  In the US, the laws regarding both the reporting of 
interest and dividend income earned abroad as well as the laws
regarding reporting of assets held outside the US
were honored more in the breach than in the observance by many, 
and especially so by
persons of Indian origin. A couple of years ago, the IRS cracked down on this
and the howls of outrage in the Indian community at having to comply
with the laws were interesting to observe.

When you actually do convert the money in your NRE account from 
INR to CAD (whether original deposit or interest earned) you may have a
loss due to the recent fall of the Indian Rupee, that is, if you close the account
and convert all the money from INR to CAD, you may get back less than the
original deposit plus all the earned interest on which you have been so
diligently paying taxes. How that loss is handled on your
tax return, or if it is regarded as a personal loss and thus
non-deductible, is a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks. Just as a side note, if it is an NRO account as opposed to NRE, then Indian govt will deduct tax on interest income, so Canadian govt. will not deduct tax again, is it right?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between deduction and payment. Only the Indian Government/tax authority can demand that an Indian bank _deduct_ tax from the interest it pays you and send the money directly to the government. That does not mean that the tax is necessarily _due_ from you. You may well be entitled to get it all back as a refund if you file a tax return in India.  The _Canadian_ government will not _deduct_ tax, but it may _assess_ tax on the _entire_ amount of interest, not what you get after GoI has gotten its cut. CRA may (or may not) give credit for tax paid to GoI.

Comment: Thanks. But if the Indian bank is deducting tax, how come it is not due from me? I could not get much info on the web about deduction vs payment, can you shed some light?

Comment: You should ask a different question about the difference between deduction and liability.